# What would be the relative xpath for the image with onclick?

Tags: xpath

I am trying to find the relative xpath for the image (please refer the image attached).
Currently I am using the following absolute xpath and it is working fine, but it is too long:

```
xpath:=//DIV[@id='ResultSection']/DIV[1]/TABLE[1]/TBODY[1]/TR[2]/TD[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/TABLE[1]/TBODY[1]/TR[15]/TD[10]/IMG[1]
```

[image]

Comment: `//img[@title='Change'][@class='ITIWebUIImage ITIWebUIIcon ITIWebUIChangeIcon']` assuming you have only one such image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple Relative Xpaths:

```
//img[@title='Change']

//img[@class='its value']

//img[@onclick='its value']
```

Multiple Combinations:  `//img[@title='Change' and @class='its value']`